# Is it possible to customize Steps of Test Case work item?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

I'm using Azure DevOps Server 2019 update 1.1 on premises.
I'd like to customize Steps of Test Case work item described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-test-cases?view=azure-devops-2019#create-test-cases

[image]

For instance, is it possible to add a new custom column in addition to default columns Action, Expected result and Attachments? If yes, how is it possibile? I'm using xml process model, is it possibile to customize columns of Steps by xml (or for instance do I have to use SDK)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Steps field` in test case uses `TestStepsControl` control. It does not support expansion and customization.

So there is no such method to add new column to the Test Steps.

For a workaround, you could try to create one custom work item control and create a new field.

For more information about using TFS custom work item control, please refer to the [this Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/narend/how-to-use-custom-controls-in-work-item-form).

Here is [a ticket](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/21e739b4-4901-40af-9452-95d1442fd16a/how-to-add-more-columns-to-teststeps-in-test-case-wit?forum=tfsprocess) about the similar requirement.

I know that this is very inconvenient. You could submit a suggestion ticket about this feature in [our UserVoice website](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).

[image]

Hope this helps.