# Is there a way to remove or add columns in an Azure Devops test case?

Tags: azure-devops, testcase, test-plan

When you add an `Azure DevOps` test case the default is for each step to have a `Steps` field, an `Action` field, an `Expected Result` field and an `Attachment` field. Is there a way to remove or add fields? For example to remove the `Attachment` field and add a `Link` field?

Comment: Hello u got any update for this? am too looking for something like this

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not. You can find the similar topics here:

- [Is it possible to customize Steps of Test Case work item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817140/is-it-possible-to-customize-steps-of-test-case-work-item)
- [Ability to add custom columns to Test Steps](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Ability-to-add-custom-columns-to-Test-St/1140030)